# Set BooleanField Value

Tags: development, custom-form, aspx, field-controls

I'm trying to set value for BooleanField on my custom NewForm.
If I try to do it from codebehind, visually it doesn't change, but when the item will be saved this field will be empty (neither true nor false):

**ASPX:**

```
<SharePoint:BooleanField runat="server" FieldName="boolField" ControlMode="New" ID="MyCustomField"/>
```

**ASPX.CS** (invokes in OnLoad method):

```
if (!SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin) // For example
{
    MyCustomField.Value = true; // Visually no changes
    MyCustomField.UpdateFieldValueInItem(); // Still nothing
}
```

I even tried to set in .aspx (and got "Parser error message"):

```
<SharePoint:BooleanField runat="server" FieldName="boolField" ControlMode="New" ID="MyCustomField" Value="TRUE"/>
```

However, if I'll try to change Field of any other type (NumberField, for example), everything will be OK.

Where am I wrong, and how can I do it from codebehind (or at least in aspx)?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

You should set the control as follow:

```
MyCustomField.ItemFieldValue = "1";
MyCustomField.Field.DefaultValue = "1";
```

Where `1` is for true, and `0` is for false

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately, I get `InvalidCastException`. Also, I have no "DefaulView" property...

Comment: `DefaultValue` it is..

Comment: Sorry, I meant I have no `DefaultValue` property! (just a typo).

Comment: Yeah! I should be using it like this:  `MyCustomField.ItemFieldValue = "1";  MyCustomField.Field.DefaultValue = "1";`

Comment: Does that work ?

Comment: No issues, the answer has been updated, please mark it correct to close the question